# Java using return value from method for if else statements

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, return

I made a method in java that prints a menu screen that looks like this:

```
MENU
c - Number of whitespace characters
f - Find text
r - Replace all !'s
q - Quit

Choose an option:
```

The method returns a char. How do I use the return value of the method in main to make if else statements?

printMenu method:

```
public static char printMenu(Scanner scnr) {
      char menuOp;

      //display the menu
      System.out.println("\nMENU");
      System.out.println( "c - Number of whitespace characters");
      System.out.println("f - Find text");
      System.out.println("r - Replace all !\'s");
      System.out.println("q - Quit\n");

      menuOp = ' ';

      //loop until the user has entered a c, f, r or q
      while (menuOp != 'c' && menuOp != 'f' &&
                menuOp != 'r' &&  
                menuOp != 'q') {
         System.out.println( "Choose an option:");
         menuOp = scnr.nextLine().charAt(0);
      }

      //return the letter that the user entered
      return menuOp;
   }  //end of the printMenu method
```

What I want to be able to do in main:

```
while (return value from printMenu method != 'q'){

      printMenu(scnr);
      if (return value from printMenu method == 'c'){ //do this                    
      }
      else if (return value from printMenu method == 'f'){ //do this
      }
      else if (return value from printMenu method == 'r'){ //do this
      }
   }
}
```

I'm still new and really appreciate the help, patience, and kindness. Thanks

*Edit* - I have to use the return value from printMenu() as a requirement for a project.

Comment: Hint: look at the line `menuOp = scnr.nextLine().charAt(0);`. Here you are assigning the _return value_ of `charAt` to `menuOp`. You should try doing something similar with `printMenu` too!

Comment: Awesome hint, that put me another step in the right direction, thanks sweeper!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a good example for using a **do-while loop**:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    char c;
    do
    {
        c = printMenu(scanner);
        switch (c)
        {
            case 'c':
                //do something
                break;
            case 'f':
                //do something
                break;
            case 'r':
                //do something
                break;

        }
    } while(c != 'q');
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered by sweeper:

```
menuChar = printMenu(scnr);
```